# Alamofire network request fired before adding completion block?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am new to Alamofire, and it's logic is a little confusing for me.
I'm doubting if Alamofire always adds completion handler only after that request fired. 
For example, here is the usage example from [Alamofire Github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

In the `.request(.GET...`method, the request itself is resumed and then returned. Right after that, the returned request then calls `.responseJSON(...`method to add a completion call back to some queue. Isn't it too late to init a call back block, as the request has already fired? Normally we always fire a request only after we has fully set it up, don't we?

However, under the supervision of Charles I found that Alamofire requests were sent out only after the `.responseJSON` method returns.

So, please tell me how did I misunderstand Alamofire's logic.
Thanks!

Comment: it is the same login in jquery success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion handler is not useful until a response has returned. And when a response has returned, Alamofire calls the handler automatically. In the event that the handler is added after the response has returned, Alamofire calls the handler immediately (this is why you can add multiple handlers at any time, they will all be called).

Answer (score 0):

How about you try like this?

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.request)  // original URL request
             print(response.response) // URL response
             print(response.data)     // server data
             print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

             let result = response.result
             switch result {
                 case .Success(let data):
                     let json = JSON(data)
                     completed(JSONObject: json, error: nil)
                     break
                 case .Failure(let error):
                      completed(JSONObject: nil, error: error)
                      break
                 }
         }
```